# How to preserve jQuery element data values when using $.merge()

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following, each element in "rows" has a jQuery .data('tag') value.

```
var rows = $('#availableTagsTable > tbody tr').has('td input:checked');
var usedTagRows = $('#usedTagsTable > tbody tr');
$.merge(usedTagRows, rows);
rows.remove();
```

After execution of $.merge() the elements in both "rows" and "usedTagRows" have the data('tag') value. However, after execution of rows.remove() the elements added to usedTagRows no longer have the data('tag') value.

How do I select elements w/ a .data() value, merge those elements into another set of elements, then remove the original elements, and retain the .data() values?,

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xm9uhkbk/1/ Is this what you are looking at?

Comment: Can I ask you what it is you're trying to achieve? `$.merge` is used for arrays, not jQuery collections as far as I'm aware. Is it the `.data()` you want to save prior to removing the elements from the DOM structure?

Comment: Is requirement to copy `.data()` from `usedTagRows` to `rows` ? If possible , can post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, $.merge() can be used to manipulate collections of elements returned from a jQuery select. I am using it here to move rows from one HTML table to another.

Comment: Just recreate the rows instead and store the cell contents and `.data()` values in an array. I think storing those DOM elements in an array and then removing them will cause unexpected behavior, because they're linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you are trying to do but I think you might have an issue with your usage of merge. It does't alter any of the lists you pass in it instead returns a new list.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/

```
var newArray = $.merge([], oldArray);
```